# .findIndex() - String is not a function. Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The Problem**

.findIndex() is breaking. I'm providing it with a string, but it's saying "It's not a function"

**Objective / Context**

Auto reply to property inquiry

**Function does the following:**

- Scans the inbox to identify inquiry.
- Breaks down the email, storing the data in
  variables.
- Scans a spreadsheet with information about all of our
  homes for sale. Matches the property ID in the email against the
  spreadsheet looking for the match.
- Replys to the email with data stored in the spreadsheet that matches that property.

**Where I am up to**

I am able to identify the email.
I'm then able to scan through the email and pull the relevant information.

**The Code**

```
function autoReply() {
var queryInbox = "is:unread from:(example@gmail.com) to:(example@gmail.com) Example Text:"; // Email Identification
var locatedEmail = GmailApp.search(queryInbox); // Search Inbox for Identification
locatedEmail.forEach(thread => {
  var messages = thread.getMessages();
  if (messages.length === 1) {
    // BREAKING DOWN THE EMAIL
    var msgBody = messages[0].getPlainBody();
    var identityNumber = msgBody.split("\n")[1].replace('Property ID: ','');
  
    // SPREADSHEET      
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('exampleId').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var column = 1; // column Index
    var columnValues = SS.getRange(2, column, SS.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(identityNumber); //Row Index - 2
    var rowID = searchResult + 2;
  
    var houseAddress = SS.getRange(rowID, 2).getValue();
  
    // EMAIL BODY
    var body = "<p>Hi, thank you for emailing us about " + houseAddress + ".</p>";
    var options = { name: "Property Enquiry", htmlBody: body };
    thread.reply(body, options);
    thread.markRead();
    thread.moveToArchive();
  }
});
}
```

**Example Email**

[image]

**Example Spreadsheet**
[image]

**Additional Information: Error is showing that it is passing a propertyID as a string to the .findIndex**

[image]

Comment: `console.log(columnValues)` are you sure you have an array?

Comment: I set up a small example script outside of my main script to get it working. It seems to work perfectly fine on its own.

Comment: A single column is still a two dimensional array try to use flat()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `columnValues` of `var columnValues = SS.getRange(2, column, SS.getLastRow()).getValues()` is 2 dimensional array like `[["sample1"],["sample2"],["sample3"],,,]`. And the argument of `findIndex` is a function. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.
- When you want to retrieve the index of `searchResult` using the value of `identityNumber`, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

From

```
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(identityNumber);
```

To

```
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(([r]) => r == identityNumber);
```

- In your script, it seems that the column "B" of the searched row is retrieved.

#### Note:

- In your situation, when [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) is used, your script can be also modified as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var columnValues = SS.getRange(2, column, SS.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
      var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(identityNumber); //Row Index - 2
      var rowID = searchResult + 2;

      var houseAddress = SS.getRange(rowID, 2).getValue();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var houseAddress = SS.getRange(2, column, SS.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(identityNumber).findNext().offset(0, 1).getValue();
    ```

#### Reference:

- [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)